Error attempting to build Selenium Grid on Windows 11 machine
I am attempting to build the selenium grid (bazel build grid) for the first time & am getting the following error:

Blockquote

ERROR: C:/users/mbarrett/_bazel_mbarrett/shbbbxvx/external/aspect_rules_esbuild~~esbuild~esbuild_win32-x64/BUILD.bazel:6:17: Extracting npm package esb...@0.23.0 [for tool] failed: (Exit 1): bash.exe failed: error executing NpmPackageExtract command (from target @@aspect_rules_esbuild~~esbuild~esbuild_win32-x64//:.aspect_rules_js/node_modules/esbuild)

Blockquote

I see in the Bazel logs that other npm packages are extracted successfully. I have followed the instructions on the Selenium site regarding setting up to build Selenium in a Windows environment here:
https://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2020/04/setting-up-windows-development.html
I have installed all the tools that are required from the documentation. I am new to building Selenium and to building with Bazel.  Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this particular error?
